# Can I add an order link in my android app?

Tags: android, google-play

I have registerred a free account in Google Play, and upload my android app to Google Play
Can I add an order link in my android app? an user will redirect to our website to order paid app when he click the link.

My location is not supported for merchants, I can't apply merchant account, I don't know if it's OK.

Comment: AFAIK its against the Play Rule ..

Comment: No it will not work if your location is not supported for merchants

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html "1.2 If you want to charge a fee for your Products, you must also acquire and maintain a valid Payment Account from an authorized Payment Processor."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must register a Payment Account in order to add an order link, the Google Documentation is very clear, see ... play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean I have to distribute my app in other way instead of Google Play if I add an order link to my website?